# Uploading App To Windows 10 Store

Tags: java, windows

I have a few questions about uploading a app to the Windows 10 store. My question is, I code in Eclipse and I created a program in JAVA, can I still upload it???

Also, if the answer to that is Yes, when I went to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh694062.aspx on one of the requirements, it said, Required (at least one package).
I might sound like a noob, but IDK what that means.

Also, heres my app that I want to add to the app store > http://www.mediafire.com/download/fm8nxv3wcmmclmo/Gadgets.jar

(this app still has bugs, I have a updated version but I have not added it to MediaFire yet).

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can't publish a Java app into windows 10 store, because `.jar` executables need Java so they are not compatible with the Windows store.

Comment: @Jbot You **can't** fix this, i've said that you can't upload java apps to Windows 10 store. Any way you can learn another language for uploading your app into this store.